# Openstack Installation

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I have tried using devstack, try to install openstack folsom. However, I can not install it with an error.

```
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon.egg-link (link to .)
horizon 2012.2.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /opt/stack/horizon
Processing dependencies for horizon==2012.2.2
error: Installed distribution python-keystoneclient 0.1.3 conflicts with requirement python-keystoneclient>=0.2
++ failed
++ local r=1
++ set +o xtrace
```

I'm doing the installation on Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Answer (score 4):

The installation requires the python-keystoneclient version is or newer than 0.2. Since you have already installed version 0.1.3, the installer failed and reported this error.

**Solution:**

1. confirm the installed package with command "apt-cache policy
   python-keystoneclient"
2. remove it with command "apt-get remove python-keystoneclient"
3. install newer version with command "apt-get install package=", for example, "apt-get install python-keystoneclient=0.2"

Answer (score 1):

You have an OS package for python-keystoneclient installed which conflicts with the version PIP is trying to install. Remove it (apt-get remove python-keystoneclient) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling in new virtual machine. I was getting this error because of some cache problem and I couldn't correct it even after clearing cache and updating. So I just reinstalled and it worked fine.

Anyways, installing it afresh always work if you are going to try something new ( make sure your internet connection doesn't break in between).

Answer (score 1):

> python-keystoneclient 0.1.3 conflicts with requirement python-keystoneclient>=0.2

According to this line, the version 0.2 of python-keystoneclient needs to be installed but what you have is 0.1.3 version of it.

Solution:

```
 sudo pip list | grep python-keystoneclient #check for the version
 sudo pip install python-keystoneclient #install the new version
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack Folsom is a pretty old release. Make sure you switched to appropriate branch\tag in DevStack git repo. As far as I know in DevStack everything specific to a release handled this way.

Also you can try set particular branches for some packages in your local.conf file. See exact parameter names in stackrc file. For example, for keystone client there is a parameter called KEYSTONECLIENT_BRANCH.